# Understanding return of 0 in numeric comparison

Tags: perl

Trying to understand some code which is written as:

```
if ($txn->result() == 1) {   # line 1014
```

When the return value is a number like 1, 1001, etc no problem. When the return value is 0, I get the infamous (notorious) *"Use of uninitialized value in string eq"* warning.

How do you specifically test for the LHS as number equal to RHS as number in this situation?

Regardless of how I try, the result in this situation is returning '' where I expected it to be false.

Comment: You should not be getting "Use of uninitialized value in string eq" for that condition. You are not using a string eq in the line you posted.

Comment: More code is needed to troubleshoot. Including line numbers of code/errors.

Comment: It's really very simple, when $txn-result() returns 0 I get the warning, when it returns a 1, 1001, 1005 no warning. Only when it returns 0 there is the warning problem. The original code was as written above, it currently is `        my $results = $txn->result();
                       
 if (defined $results)
          {
            if ($results == 1)
              {
` with same result _Use of uninitialized value in string eq at /usr/local/billing/bin//../lib/Billing.pm line 1014._

Comment: I also understand that comparisons return 1 for true and a special version of the empty string for false. My question should have been, how to test for the numeric value 1 when function returns 0.

Comment: err, do you mean `$txn-result()` or `$txn->result()`?  they are very very different things

Comment: @tgunr: when a function does return 0, you test for 1 by simply say `== 1`.  You have something else going on here.

Comment: @ysth Thanks, corrected the call to ->

Comment: Yes, I think there is something else going on but don't understand why the warning, and why does it report in the error "using eq". Isn't that for string comparison?

Comment: Are you *really* getting an "uninitialized value in string eq" error message on a line that doesn't use the `eq` operator? Please double check that you're looking at the correct line of the correct file. Can you create a small test case that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Is there an `elsif` clause?  Perl used to have a problem reporting line numbers of those as the original `if` line.

Comment: I'd suggest to add a explicit `return 0;`at the top of the result method and see whether the warning still occors. It looks to me as if the warning is emitted by some other part of your code.

Comment: Yes, there are two following elseif statements, I will snip them to test your statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message you report does not comes from the code you posted. That message comes from `eq undef`, not from `== 0`.

```
$ perl -we'if (123 == 0) { }'

$ perl -we'if (123 == undef) { }'
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1.

$ perl -we'if (123 eq undef) { }'
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at -e line 1.
```

You can check if a value is undefined ("uninitialized") using the [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) function. That said, I bet it's not needed here. If `->result` returns true on success and false on error, you should simply check that.

```
if ($txn->result()) {
```

Aside from being simpler, this has the added advantage of avoid undefined warnings if `undef` is used for false.